# How to avoid input value reset in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am referring to this tutorial for simple react autocomplete https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-autocomplete

But I have a slightly different requirement. Instead of typing something on the `input` field, I want all the suggestions to come up on clicking the `input` field. I am basically implementing a requirement where on clicking the `input` field, it should show user what are the available options.

Here is my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-easley-wdm5x

Specifically in the `Autocomplete.jsx` file (as mentioned below)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Autocomplete extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array)
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    suggestions: []
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // The active selection's index
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      // The suggestions that match the user's input
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      // Whether or not the suggestion list is shown
      showSuggestions: false,
      // What the user has entered
      userInput: ""
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const { suggestions } = this.props;
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    // Filter our suggestions that don't contain the user's input
    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      (suggestion) =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );

    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions,
      showSuggestions: true,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  };

  onClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
    });
  };

  onClick2 = (e) => {
    console.log("text check", e.currentTarget.innerText);
    if (e.currentTarget.innerText === "") {
      const { suggestions } = this.props;
      const filteredSuggestions = suggestions;
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions: true,
        userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
      });
    }
  };

  onKeyDown = (e) => {
    const { activeSuggestion, filteredSuggestions } = this.state;

    // User pressed the enter key
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        showSuggestions: false,
        userInput: filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]
      });
    }
    // User pressed the up arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion - 1 });
    }
    // User pressed the down arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion + 1 });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick2,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,
      state: {
        activeSuggestion,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions,
        userInput
      }
    } = this;

    let suggestionsListComponent;

    if (showSuggestions) {
      if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <ul className="suggestions">
            {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              let className;

              // Flag the active suggestion with a class
              if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                className = "suggestion-active";
              }

              return (
                <li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                  {suggestion}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <div className="no-suggestions">
            <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
          onClick={onClick2}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

In the `input` element in return section,

```
<input
          type="text"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
          onClick={onClick2}
/>
```

I have added a `onClick` functionality that calls the function `onClick2`.

```
onClick2 = (e) => {
    console.log("text check", e.currentTarget.innerText);
    if (e.currentTarget.innerText === "") {
      const { suggestions } = this.props;
      const filteredSuggestions = suggestions;
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions: true,
        userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
      });
    }
  };
```

My function simply returns all the suggestions back on clicking the `input` field. I am able to select items from suggestions and it gets put in the `input` field. **But when I click on the input field again, the value disappears.**

I want this autocomplete suggestion to only show once on clicking the empty `input` field and after selecting the item from list, I should be able to edit the value further.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input values are not stored into innerText, but in value prop.

Look at this:

```
onClick2 = (e) => {
    console.log("text check", e.currentTarget.innerText);
    if (e.currentTarget.value === "") {
      const { suggestions } = this.props;
      const filteredSuggestions = suggestions;
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions: true,
        userInput: e.currentTarget.value
      });
    }
  };
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the wrong check in onClick2 function. Instead of checking e.currentTarget.innerText === "", it has to be e.target.value as we are validating the text in input field.

```
onClick2 = (e) => {
    console.log("text check", e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      const { suggestions } = this.props;
      const filteredSuggestions = suggestions;
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions: true,
        userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
      });
    }
  };
```

Here is the working link - https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-meadow-5fr6x?file=/src/Autocomplete.jsx:1344-1711